# How to populate TableViewCell with JSON data using Codable protocol in Swift4?

Tags: tableview, swift4

**Solved**

I am trying to populate Table View Cell from sample **JSON** in this link https://api.myjson.com/bins/13axs1, but getting error in cellForRowAt function when trying to assign textLabel.

> type '[City]?' has no subscript members

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "New York",
    "information": "Later will be added",
    "imageUrl": "later"
  },
  {
    "name": "New York",
    "information": "Later will be added",
    "imageUrl": "later"
  }
]
```

The code in ViewController:

```
struct City: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let information: String?
    let imageUrl: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var citiesList: [City] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/13axs1"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: data)

                if cities != nil{
                   self.citiesList = cities
               }else {
                   print("nothing to display")
               }

               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
               }

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }

        }.resume()

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return citiesList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = citiesList[indexPath.row].name // here I am getting error type '[City]? has no subscript members
        return cell
    }
}
```

Sorry, but I don't know why not all of the code shows clearly after I added it, but hope it will be clear for you guys to understand, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you getting an error message (if so, post it in your original post) or is the data not showing up in your tableview ?

Comment: @nathan, yes, I am getting an error message and xCode does't let me to build the project. In cellForRowAt when trying to assign cell's textLabel I am getting error 'type '[City]? has no subscript members'.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the reload method (`reloadData()`):

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {
        let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: data)
        self.citiesList = cities

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error serializing json:", error)
    }

}.resume()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.deque...
    cell.textLabel?.text = citiesList?[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting 'Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(.:numberOfRowsInSection)' error in the line of self.tableView.reloadData() and it doesn't let me to build project.

Comment: What's your tableview variable called ?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to make a variable of table view. Now I made and it builds, but crashes with error 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at the row  return citiesList!.count where the numberOfRowsInSection fuction is.

Comment: Because your variable is an optional. `citiesList?.count ?? 0`. If you have any more errors, search and create a new post if needed. Your OP was answered.

Comment: I have solved all issues by changing some things in the code, you helped me a lot, thanks mate :)